# Python queue.Queue synchronization issue

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I am trying to read pulses from and encoder using the pigpio library. The library seems good for encoder pulses but when i try to use pigpio.callback() to get pulses for two different gpio pins I am facing issues. Here is the code.

```
class encoder_T(Thread):
    def __init__(self, pinNumber, scale_value, gpio, queue, lock):
        super().__init__()
        self.gpio = gpio
        self.pinNumber = pinNumber
        self.cb1 = self.gpio.callback(self.pinNumber, pigpio.RISING_EDGE, self.callback_func)
        self.scale_value = scale_value
        self.position_pulses = 0
        self.queue = queue
        self.position_degrees = 0 
        self.direction = 0
        self.lock = lock
        
    def callback_func(self, pinNumber, level, tick):
      
        if self.gpio.read(config.DIRECTION_TRAINING) == 0:
            self.direction = 1
        else:
            self.direction = -1
        self.position_pulses += self.direction
        self.position_degrees = ((self.position_pulses % config.TR_CALIBRATION_VALUE + config.TR_CALIBRATION_VALUE) % config.TR_CALIBRATION_VALUE * self.scale_value) / config.TR_CALIBRATION_VALUE
        with self.lock:
            self.queue.put_nowait(format(self.position_degrees,".2f"))
        #print (self.queue.get())
    
    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.000001)

class UdpSender(Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue1, lock):
        super().__init__()
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.queue1 = queue1
        self.num1=0
        self.lock = lock
        
    def run(self):
        while True:
            with self.lock:
                if not self.queue1.empty():
                    self.num1 = self.queue1.get_nowait()
                else:
                    continue
            message = "{}, {}".format(self.num1, self.num1)
            print (message)
            self.sock.sendto(message.encode('utf-8'), (config.MULTICAST_ADDRESS, config.MULTICAST_PORT))
            time.sleep(0.000001)


class Encoder_Process(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.gpio = pigpio.pi()
        lock = threading.Lock()
        self.queue1 = queue.Queue()
        self.num1 = encoder_T(8,360, self.gpio, self.queue1, lock)
        self.udp1 = UdpSender(self.queue1, lock)

    def run(self):
        self.num1.start()
        self.udp1.start()
        self.num1.join()
        self.udp1.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p2 = Encoder_Process()
    p2.start()
    p2.join()
```

What I am doing is making two different threads, one reads the encoder pulses using the pigpio.callback() and puts it on an queue.Queue(). the UdpSender thread then reads that queue and sends a relevant UdpPacket. I am initializing these two threads inside a multiprocess.Process(), because of making many threads for other purposes was slowing down everything.

My current issue is that the Queue does not get emptied by UdpSender thread. I have even tried Lock to make sure that only one thread gets the access of the queue at one time. Remember the pi can read the pulses accurately but these are quite fast so when i modify this code for two gpio (two encoders) this also does not work.

I have tried many different things but my I am stuck at a point where only one time the queue gets filled and the UdpSender does not empty the queue and hence the code does not continue. WHat I think is that this is called a race condition in multithreading

Answer (score 0):

`queue.Queue`s do not need to be locked, and are specifically designed to work correctly in a multithreading environment. You can get rid of the lock.

I'm not sure why your `UdpSender.run` method isn't just:

```
while True:
    self.num1 = self.queue1.get()
    ... handle value
```

Part of the problem is that your UdpSender is in a busy loop.  It is eating up all your cycles.  It's possible that it's preventing the encoder for catching the message in a timely fashion.

I should also add that you have provided no means for UdpSender to terminate.  The `.join()` on that process will never return.